# How to change the default padding scale from 'rem' to 'px'?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to change the padding default scale from `rem` to `px`. I tried below workaround but it didn't work:

> Open your tailwind.config.js file.
>
> Locate the theme section within the configuration object.
>
> Inside the theme section, add or modify the padding property to specify the unit as px.

I tried to set the default padding scale/unit to `px` in the tailwind.config.js file.

I am expecting the padding default scale from `rem` to `px`.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider extending the `padding` key in the Tailwind configuration to replace the default spacing units from `rem` to `px` like:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      padding: {
        '0.5': '2px',
        1: '4px',
        2: '8px',
        // Etc.
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is an issue on their GitHub that includes various methods to do so](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1232). Here are some popular methods I've seen in the issue:

### [Looping over the theme](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1232#issuecomment-1330042062)

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

function rem2px(input, fontSize = 16) {
  if (input == null) {
    return input;
  }
  switch (typeof input) {
    case 'object':
      if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        return input.map((val) => rem2px(val, fontSize));
      }
      const ret = {};
      for (const key in input) {
        ret[key] = rem2px(input[key], fontSize);
      }
      return ret;
    case 'string':
      return input.replace(
        /(\d*\.?\d+)rem$/,
        (_, val) => `${parseFloat(val) * fontSize}px`,
      );
    case 'function':
      return eval(input.toString().replace(
        /(\d*\.?\d+)rem/g,
        (_, val) => `${parseFloat(val) * fontSize}px`,
      ));
    default:
      return input;
  }
}

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: rem2px(defaultTheme),
};
```

### [`@thedutchcoder/postcss-rem-to-px`](https://github.com/TheDutchCoder/postcss-rem-to-px)

Converts `rem` to `px` in your css file.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
   '@thedutchcoder/postcss-rem-to-px': {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```